# Change Telerik subreport path

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a problem with Telerik Reporting.
I have defined main report in trdx file. It contains subreport, also defined in trdx file. In designer it is working fine but when I've put this report on my website I'm getting an error: `"An error has occurred while processing SubReport 'company_address': Could not find file 'something\Organizers.trdx'. "`

It is searching for the report in default working directory of my web application, but I store my reports id different folder. Can I change it programmatically? I don't want to hardcode in designer the path for subreport (and I don't know if it is even possible).

Few words about how I use these reports. I have ASP.NET application. I scan for all *.trdx files in given folder and I deserialize them using ReportXmlSerializer. Everything is working fine, except the reports with subreports.

Do you have any idea how can I change path of subreport if report have one?